# Ajax GET for error_log contents works locally but returns 403 on server

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache

I have that tiny script :

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function(event, state) {
            var path = $(this).data("path");
            console.log(path);
            $.ajax({
              type:"GET",
              url: path,
              dataType: 'text',
              contentType: 'text',
              async: true,
              success: function (data) {
                  $("#file-content").text(data);
              }
          });
        });     
});
</script>
```

and HTML part is :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-path="/error_log">error_log</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-path="/log.txt">log.txt</button>
<div id="file-content" style="white-space: pre-line;"></div>
```

That code works perfectly on my Macbook, running apache locally. But once uploaded on my server, the loading of /log.txt works perfectly BUT loading error_log file returns 403 error. I checked permissions on those files and they are exactly the same permissions :

```
-rw-r--r--.  1 XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX  1000 14 aoû 23:00 error_log
-rw-r--r--.  1 XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX  6032 16 aoû 09:55 log.txt
```

I can't figure out the problem. Could you help me please ??

Best regards,

T.

Comment: Your server is misconfigured, 403 means Forbidden - this simply means, you are not allowed to access the file on the server via http.

Comment: Probably you have a web application firewall in place which blocks suspicious requests like these. In normal circumstances only attackers will try to read an error log file directly over the Internet.

Comment: @Flo Ok but why, since permissions and group settings on 'error_log' file are exactly the same than the 'log.txt' file which the script can load... ?

Comment: how am i supposed to know? you should check over your apache settings. first guess would be that the log file has a file extension `.txt` and the error file not. its named error_log without a file extension.
so probably your apache is not configured to serve files without an extension.